# Why does Mathematica only solve this indefinite integral for two values of n?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, integral-equations

I'm trying to estimate this integrate:

[image]

where "a" and "b" are real constants and n> 0.

I use the code

```
Integrate[(Cos[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Theta]])^(2/n - 1)/(a^2*Cos[\[Theta]]^(4/n) + b^2*Sin[\[Theta]]^(4/n))^(3/2), \[Theta]]
```

But Mathematica does not show any analytic expression after 3 hours running unless I set n = 1 or n = 2 beforehand.

Is this happen because of my weak system or I have some mistakes? I appreciate any help.

Comment: `Integrate` is an exact solver. It won't "estimate" anything. Did you really mean estimate? Or evaluate? -- Is there some reason to believe the integral has a simple solution when $2/n$ is not an integer? Without `Assumptions`, `Integrate` will treat all parameters as arbitrary complex numbers. Is that what you want?

Comment: most likely because for $n=1,n=2$ things simplify and Mathematica can find relations it can use, but not for general $n$.  btw, it also works for $n=-1,n=-2$.  For example, we all know that $\sin^n x  + \cos^n x = 1$ when $n=2$.  But about for general $n$?  That is why for specific values of $n$ things can become simpler.

Comment: I understand now
Thank you so much